# How to have second loop inside my first loop

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I am using [array-to-xml](https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml) package and I have sample (static) data like this one

```
<RECIEVEITEM operation="Add" REQUESTID="1">
            <TRANSACTIONID>264276</TRANSACTIONID>
            <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
                <KeyID>1</KeyID>
                <ITEMNO>7GE65B</ITEMNO>
                <QUANTITY>5</QUANTITY>
                <ITEMUNIT>UNT</ITEMUNIT>
                <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
                <ITEMRESERVED1 />
                <ITEMRESERVED2 />
                <ITEMRESERVED3 />
                <ITEMRESERVED4 />
                <ITEMRESERVED5 />
                <ITEMRESERVED6 />
                <ITEMRESERVED7 />
                <ITEMRESERVED8 />
                <ITEMRESERVED9 />
                <ITEMRESERVED10 />
                <ITEMOVDESC>PRINTER HP DESKJET 2135 (7GE65B) NEW</ITEMOVDESC>
                <UNITPRICE />
                <ITEMDISCPC />
                <TAXCODES />
                <GROUPSEQ />
                <POSEQ />
                <BRUTOUNITPRICE>0</BRUTOUNITPRICE>
                <WAREHOUSEID>345346</WAREHOUSEID>
                <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
                <RISEQ />
                <SNHISTORY operation="Ret"><SERIALNUMBER>A1</SERIALNUMBER><EXPIREDDATE>2020-06-30</EXPIREDDATE><QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY><SNSIGN>1</SNSIGN></SNHISTORY>
                <SNHISTORY operation="Ret"><SERIALNUMBER>A2</SERIALNUMBER><EXPIREDDATE>2020-06-30</EXPIREDDATE><QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY><SNSIGN>1</SNSIGN></SNHISTORY>
                <SNHISTORY operation="Ret"><SERIALNUMBER>A3</SERIALNUMBER><EXPIREDDATE>2020-06-30</EXPIREDDATE><QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY><SNSIGN>1</SNSIGN></SNHISTORY>
                <SNHISTORY operation="Ret"><SERIALNUMBER>A4</SERIALNUMBER><EXPIREDDATE>2020-06-30</EXPIREDDATE><QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY><SNSIGN>1</SNSIGN></SNHISTORY>
                <SNHISTORY operation="Ret"><SERIALNUMBER>A5</SERIALNUMBER><EXPIREDDATE>2020-06-30</EXPIREDDATE><QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY><SNSIGN>1</SNSIGN></SNHISTORY>
                <RIID />
            </ITEMLINE>
            <INVOICENO>PO-TEST1</INVOICENO>
            <INVOICEDATE>2020-06-30</INVOICEDATE>
            <TAX1ID>T</TAX1ID>
            <TAX1CODE>T</TAX1CODE>
            <TAX2CODE />
            <TAX1RATE>10</TAX1RATE>
            <TAX2RATE>0</TAX2RATE>
            <RATE>1</RATE>
            <INCLUSIVETAX>0</INCLUSIVETAX>
            <INVOICEISTAXABLE>1</INVOICEISTAXABLE>
            <CASHDISCOUNT>0</CASHDISCOUNT>
            <CASHDISCPC />
            <INVOICEAMOUNT>0</INVOICEAMOUNT>
            <TERMSID>Net 30</TERMSID>
            <FOB />
            <PURCHASEORDERNO />
            <WAREHOUSEID>345346</WAREHOUSEID>
            <DESCRIPTION>PO-TEST1</DESCRIPTION>
            <SHIPDATE>2020-06-30</SHIPDATE>
            <POSTED>0</POSTED>
            <FISCALRATE>1</FISCALRATE>
            <INVFROMPR />
            <TAXDATE>2020-06-30</TAXDATE>
            <VENDORID>PT ECS INDO JAYA</VENDORID>
            <SEQUENCENO>PO-TEST1</SEQUENCENO>
            <APACCOUNT>2000.01</APACCOUNT>
            <SHIPVENDID />
            <INVTAXNO2 />
            <INVTAXNO1 />
            <SSPDATE />
            <EXPENSESOFBILLID />
            <EXPENSESJOURNALDATETYPE />
            <LOCKED_BY />
            <LOCKED_TIME />
        </RECIEVEITEM>
```

As you can see tag `SNHISTORY` includes array, since `RECIEVEITEM` itself is inside an array I would like to know how can I achieve to have `SNHISTORY` array?

## Code

> Commented issue part for you to find is faster :)

```php
public function exportReturn(Request $request) {
    $returnProducts = ReturnProduct::with(['barcode', 'barcode.product', 'barcode.product.allBarcodes', 'outlet', 'user',])->get();

    foreach($returnProducts as $item) {
        $year = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->year;
        $month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->month;
        $array  = [
            "TRANSACTIONS" => [
                '_attributes' => [
                    'OnError' => 'CONTINUE'
                ],
                'RECIEVEITEM' => [ // image 1
                    '_attributes' => [
                        'operation' => 'Add',
                        'REQUESTID' => '1'
                    ],
                    'TRANSACTIONID' => $item['id'],
                    'ITEMLINE' => [
                        '_attributes' => [
                            'operation' => 'Add'
                        ],
                        'KeyID' => $item['barcode']['product']['id'],
                        'ITEMNO' => $item['barcode']['product']['sku'],
                        'QUANTITY' => $item['barcodes']['product']->allBarcodes->count(),
                        'ITEMUNIT' =>  $item['barcode']['product']['unit'],
                        'UNITRATIO' => '1',
                        'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
                        'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
                        'ITEMOVDESC' => $item['barcode']['product']['name'],
                        'UNITPRICE' => $item['barcode']['product']['price'],
                        'ITEMDISCPC' => '',
                        'TAXCODES' => '',
                        'GROUPSEQ' => '',
                        'POSEQ' => '',
                        'BRUTOUNITPRICE' => '0',
                        'WAREHOUSEID' => $item['outlet']['code'],
                        'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
                        'RISEQ' => '',
                        'SNHISTORY' => [ // array of product barcodes
                            '_attributes' => [
                                'operation' => 'Ret'
                            ],
                            foreach($item['barcodes']['product']->allBarcodes as $bb) {  // this is WRONG (is just here for you to know about data that I need to place here "logic purpose only")
                                'SERIALNUMBER' => $bb['serial_number'] ? $bb['serial_number'] : $bb['u_serial_number'],
                                'EXPIREDDATE' => $bb['created_at'],
                                'QUANTITY' => '1',
                                'SNSIGN' => '1',
                            }
                        ],
                        'RIID' => '',
                    ],
                    'INVOICENO' => 'POINS-001', //test
                    'INVOICEDATE' => '2020-06-10', //test
                    'TAX1ID' => 'T', //test
                    'TAX1CODE' => 'T', //test
                    'TAX2CODE' => '',
                    'TAX1RATE' => '10', //test
                    'TAX2RATE' => '0', //test
                    'RATE' => '1', //test
                    'INCLUSIVETAX' => '0', //test
                    'INVOICEISTAXABLE' => '1', //test
                    'CASHDISCOUNT' => '0', //test
                    'CASHDISCPC' => '',
                    'INVOICEAMOUNT' => '0', //test
                    'TERMSID' => 'Net 30', //test
                    'FOB' => '',
                    'PURCHASEORDERNO' => '',
                    'WAREHOUSEID' => $outlet['code'], //test
                    'DESCRIPTION' => '', // reason of return goes here
                    'SHIPDATE' => '2020-06-10', //test
                    'POSTED' => '0', //test
                    'FISCALRATE' => '1', //test
                    'INVFROMPR' => '',
                    'TAXDATE' => '2020-06-10', //test
                    'VENDORID' => 'PT ECS INDO JAYA', //test
                    'SEQUENCENO' => 'POINS-001', //test
                    'APACCOUNT' => '2000.01', //test
                    'SHIPVENDID' => '',
                    'INVTAXNO2' => '',
                    'INVTAXNO1' => '',
                    'SSPDATE' => '',
                    'EXPENSESOFBILLID' => '',
                    'EXPENSESJOURNALDATETYPE' => '',
                    'LOCKED_BY' => '',
                    'LOCKED_TIME' => '',
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    $filename = 'returns.xml';
    $result = ArrayToXml::convert($array, [
        'rootElementName' => 'NMEXML',
        '_attributes' => [
            'EximID'=> "12551",
            'BranchCode'=> $item['outlet']['code'],
            'ACCOUNTANTCOPYID'=> ""
        ]
    ]);
    Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, $result);
    $fullPath = url('exports', $filename);

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $fullPath
    ]);
}
```

## Questions

1. How to loop `SNHISTORY` data?

## UPDATE

I have changed my code like:

```
$array = [];
foreach($returnProducts as $item) {
    $year = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->year;
    $month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->month;
    foreach($item['barcode']['product']->allBarcodes as $bb) {
        $shin[] = [
            'SERIALNUMBER' => $bb['serial_number'] ? $bb['serial_number'] : $bb['u_serial_number'],
            'EXPIREDDATE' => $bb['created_at'],
            'QUANTITY' => '1',
            'SNSIGN' => '1',
        ];
    }

    $array['RECIEVEITEM'] = [
        '_attributes' => [
            'operation' => 'Add',
            'REQUESTID' => '1'
        ],
        'TRANSACTIONID' => $item['id'],
        'ITEMLINE' => [
            '_attributes' => [
                'operation' => 'Add'
            ],
            'KeyID' => $item['barcode']['product']['id'],
            'ITEMNO' => $item['barcode']['product']['sku'],
            'QUANTITY' => $item['barcode']['product']->allBarcodes->count(),
            'ITEMUNIT' =>  $item['barcode']['product']['unit'],
            'UNITRATIO' => '1',
            'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
            'ITEMOVDESC' => $item['barcode']['product']['name'],
            'UNITPRICE' => $item['barcode']['product']['price'],
            'ITEMDISCPC' => '',
            'TAXCODES' => '',
            'GROUPSEQ' => '',
            'POSEQ' => '',
            'BRUTOUNITPRICE' => '0',
            'WAREHOUSEID' => $item['outlet']['code'],
            'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
            'RISEQ' => '',
            'SNHISTORY' => [
                '_attributes' => [
                    'operation' => 'Ret'
                ],
                $shin,
            ],
            'RIID' => '',
        ],
        'INVOICENO' => 'POINS-001', //test
        'INVOICEDATE' => '2020-06-10', //test
        'TAX1ID' => 'T', //test
        'TAX1CODE' => 'T', //test
        'TAX2CODE' => '',
        'TAX1RATE' => '10', //test
        'TAX2RATE' => '0', //test
        'RATE' => '1', //test
        'INCLUSIVETAX' => '0', //test
        'INVOICEISTAXABLE' => '1', //test
        'CASHDISCOUNT' => '0', //test
        'CASHDISCPC' => '',
        'INVOICEAMOUNT' => '0', //test
        'TERMSID' => 'Net 30', //test
        'FOB' => '',
        'PURCHASEORDERNO' => '',
        'WAREHOUSEID' => $item['outlet']['code'], //test
        'DESCRIPTION' => '', // reason of return goes here
        'SHIPDATE' => '2020-06-10', //test
        'POSTED' => '0', //test
        'FISCALRATE' => '1', //test
        'INVFROMPR' => '',
        'TAXDATE' => '2020-06-10', //test
        'VENDORID' => 'PT ECS INDO JAYA', //test
        'SEQUENCENO' => 'POINS-001', //test
        'APACCOUNT' => '2000.01', //test
        'SHIPVENDID' => '',
        'INVTAXNO2' => '',
        'INVTAXNO1' => '',
        'SSPDATE' => '',
        'EXPENSESOFBILLID' => '',
        'EXPENSESJOURNALDATETYPE' => '',
        'LOCKED_BY' => '',
        'LOCKED_TIME' => '',
    ];
}
```

Now if I do `return response()->json($shin);` it returns data just as I need them

[image: one]

But When I try to use `$shin` in my code (as you see in my update code it doesn't work.

**Error?** it give error about 100 lines above my code (really not helpful error message)

here is the error in preview tab

```
exception: "DOMException"
file: "..........\vendor\spatie\array-to-xml\src\ArrayToXml.php"
line: 152
message: "Invalid Character Error"
```

here is where i track my controller in response tab

```
   {
        "file": "........\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\XmlExportController.php",
        "line": 869,
        "function": "convert",
        "class": "Spatie\\ArrayToXml\\ArrayToXml",
        "type": "::"
    },
    {
        "function": "exportReturn",
        "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\XmlExportController",
        "type": "->"
    },
```

**Any idea?**

## UPDATE 2

Well I managed to get my `SNHISTORY` looped data as array but the issue is while `$item['barcode']['product']->allBarcodes` only includes current product barcodes during print somehow it print all barcodes even from other products.

```
foreach($item['barcode']['product']->allBarcodes as $bb) {
    $shin[] = [
        '_attributes' => [
            'operation' => 'Ret'
        ],
        'SERIALNUMBER' => $bb['serial_number'] ? $bb['serial_number'] : $bb['u_serial_number'],
        'EXPIREDDATE' => $bb['created_at'],
        'QUANTITY' => '1',
        'SNSIGN' => '1',
    ];
}
```

and in my xml code

```
'SNHISTORY' => [
  $shin,
],
```

now it prints like:

[image: two]

result of `return response()->json($item['barcode']['product']->allBarcodes);`

[image: three]

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

After doing `UPDATE 2` i could fix my extra data by adding `$shin = [];` above my loop code.

```
$shin = [];
foreach($item['barcode']['product']->allBarcodes as $bb) {
    $shin[] = [
        '_attributes' => [
            'operation' => 'Ret'
        ],
        'SERIALNUMBER' => $bb->serial_number ? $bb->serial_number : $bb->u_serial_number,
        'EXPIREDDATE' => $bb->created_at,
        'QUANTITY' => '1',
        'SNSIGN' => '1',
    ];
}
```

and

```
'SNHISTORY' => [
  $shin,
],
```

Works as it should be now.